# Shell tests in Automake

Tags: testing, command-line, automake

I want Automake to run a sequence of tests, each being a command line, e.g.:

```
./mytest mydata1.dat
./mytest mydata2.dat mydata3.dat
./mytest mydata4.dat
```

Is there a way to do that without having to create a separate .sh file for each test?

Comment: There's basically a whole [chapter](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Tests) on running test suites with automake, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Yes. I've read that. Still not sure whether it is possible to run arbitrary command line as a test.